# gradle compileJava error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist

Tags: java, gradle, junit5

I can't manage to use gradle to get JUnit5 tests to work, compileJava failes with a message that it can't find org.junit.jupiter.api, despite me having put it in the dependencies.

I have to compile some code that was give to me. It has a directory structure like this:

```
├── build.gradle
├── src
│   ├── frame
│   │   ├── CardTestfileReader.java
│   │   ├── PublicTests.java
│   │   └── SortArray.java
│   └── lab
│       ├── Card.java
│       ├── HybridSort.java
│       ├── HybridSortRandomPivot.java
│       └── YourTests.java
└── tests
    └── public
        ├── TestFile1
        ├── TestFile2
        └── TestFile3
```

The JUnit5 tests are in frame.PublicTests, I need to run those.

I managed to copypasta this `build.groovy` file without really understanding what it is doing.

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'checkstyle'
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2')
  testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2')
}

test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
  testLogging {
    events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
  }
}

sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir 'src'
    }
  }

  test {
    java {
      srcDir 'src'
    }
  }
}
```

I'm hoping to get `gradle test` to work and run the unit tests somehow.

Answer (score 3):

With Gradle, the same project can have multiple configurations (in example "main" and "test"), and each configuration may have a different classpath. You are importing the `junit5` dependencies using the directive `testCompile('org.junit...')` ; but that includes the junit5 jar in the **test** configuration only.

Note that the `PublicTests` class is placed under `main`, so Gradle will compile this under the "main" configuration. If `PublicTests` references junit5, then this will cause the compilation error (since junit5 is not included in the "main" classpath).

Long story short.. You should put all your tests under `test`.

You can check the classpath for every configuration by calling `gradle dependencies`.

Comment: The code was given to me, I can't change the structure of it. But you were right. I was able to get it to work by changing `testCompile('...')` to `compile('...')`!

Comment: Don't put junit on your compile classpath!! You'll end up putting junit into production! Junit is a test time dependency, it should never be a compile/runtime dependency!

Answer (score 3):

You have this strange setup where both "main" and "test" source sets reference the same "src" folder.

So, `PublicTests.java` is actually in two source sets (both main and test). So there's actually two compile tasks which point to the exact same sources. The "main" source set is failing to compile because junit is not on your compile classpath.

*** DO NOT PUT JUNIT ON THE COMPILE CLASSPATH TO FIX THIS ***

Your build is messed up and you need to separate your tests from your main sources, and stop sharing the "src" folder with both source sets.

Do yourself a favour and stick to Gradle's sensible defaults. Put your application code in `src/main/java` and put your tests in `src/test/java`

Comment: Nice explanation. I was trying to implement my test case in main instead of test. For my scenarios I don't want it in main specifically. So it works for me!